# GAS - upload file to drive with version

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I can use GAS script to upload a file to my drive as below:

```
media = MediaFileUpload(
    filename,
    mimetype=mimetype,
    resumable=True
)
request = service.files().create(
    media_body=media,
    body={'name': remotefilename, 'parents': [folderId]}
)
```

But if I upload the same file multiple times, it will generate multiple copies. Is it possible to keep the same file but keep different version? just like what the UI update version does?

Comment: Uploading a new file won't replace the old file unless you remove the old ones in your code.  In google drive filenames can be the same.  The file ids are the unique identifier of a file.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

Instead of a `create` request, you can issue an `update` request to an existing file with `newRevision` parameter set to `true` to create a new revision for the same file.

For more information on how to use `Files: update`, you can check the [official API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#examples).

Comment: Looks like v3 has removed this field! I got below error:     raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "newRevision"

Comment: @lucky1928 Try using the [Google Apps Script Advanced Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), it is mapped to V2.